# Showing selected values from drop down list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i want to select values from select drop down list and print them in <div

like if i select 0  and prints 0 automatically

like values are 0 4 5

```
<select>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
</select>

<select>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
</select>

<div id="show_values"><!--345 --></div>
```

Comment: what is your question, please add details ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by using `jquery`'s `change` event and append values on your `div` when changing options in this way.

```js
$('select').on('change', function (e) {

    var txt = $(this).val();
    $('#show_values').append(txt+" ");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
</select>

<select>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
</select>

<div id="show_values"></div>
```

Comment: thanks Hossan thats what i need, i was up voting but waiting for 6 minutes as stack over flow rule, but how can i space printed values coz the not spaced

Comment: It's ok if it helps accept and upvote will be very appreciated. If you would like to add an extra space you can append that to the text. I've done that for you in my updated answer. Have a look at that, please.